# Ordena array de mayor a menor / menor a mayor en Java

Tags: java, array, random

Hola estoy intentando hacer un programa en java que ordene un array de n enteros, de mayor a menor y de menor a mayor , el problema que me encuentro es que cuando cargo la matriz los numeros son muy grandes el aleatorio , quiero que la clase random , me genere un numero entero en un rango dado y eso sean los datos de mi matriz, por ejmplo

minimo 1: maximo 10: , entonces la matriz solo tendra valores random del 1 al 10 pero sin repetirse, ¿Como puedo programar esto?

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente :

```
package Array;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class OrdenarMatriz {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int F;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese la cantidad de filas ");
        F=leer.nextInt();
        
        int[] matriz= cargarMatriz(F);
        mostrarMatriz(matriz);
        //
        int[] matrizorden= ordenaMatrizMenorMayor(matriz);

        System.out.println("\nOrdenada...");

        mostrarMatriz(matrizorden);
        
        //
        System.out.println("Termino...");

    }
    
    private static int[] ordenaMatrizMenorMayor(int[] matriz){
        int tamano= matriz.length;
        
        for (int i=0 ; i <tamano; i++){

            //System.out.println("Leyendo .."+i);       
            for (int j=0 ; j < tamano-i ;j++ ){
                System.out.print("\n" + i + "," + j + ",");     
                
                if ( (j +1) < tamano && matriz[j]> matriz[j+1]){    
                    int aux;
                    aux=matriz[j];
                    matriz[j]= matriz[j+1];
                    matriz[j+1]=aux;
                }
                 mostrarMatriz(matriz);
                
            }
        }
        return matriz;
    }
    
    private static void mostrarMatriz(int[] matriz){
                
        for (int i=0 ; i <matriz.length; i++){
                System.out.print(   matriz[i]+ (i+1< matriz.length ?  "," : ""));   
        }
    }

    private static int [] cargarMatriz(int F){
        int [] matriz =new int[F];
        
        for (int i=0 ; i<F; i++){
                Random rnd = new Random ();
                matriz[i]= rnd.nextInt();
        }
        return matriz;
        
    }
    private static int getRandom(int min, int max){
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Si tu `Array` va a tener valores aleatorios enteros dentro de un rango, digamos de `m` hasta `n`, entonces su tamaño no puede ser mayor a `n - m` para que no se repita ningún número dentro del rango. ¿Podrías aclarar un poco lo que intentas lograr y dónde tienes tu problema o error específico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para comenzar donde vas a guardar los números aleatorios generados va ser dentro de un vector (unidimensional) y no una matriz (bidimensional).
Para generar números aleatorios puedes usar `MATH.RANDOM()`, ahora si quieres que los valores generados se encuentran en un rango entre `m` y `n` se realiza de la siguiente manera.

```
(Math.random()*n+m);
```

Otro detalle es que elimines las líneas de código donde muestras mensaje de salida incluido `mostrarMatriz(matriz)` del método `ordenaMatrizMenorMayor` debido a que este método está creado para ordenar la matriz y no tiene que realizar ninguna otra función. El método `getRandom` no tiene ningún uso dentro programa.

Te comparto el código con las correcciones antes mencionadas

```
public class OrdenarMatriz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int longitud;
        Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Ingrese longitud del Vector: ");
        longitud=leer.nextInt();
        
        int[] matriz= cargarMatriz(longitud);
        System.out.println("\t MOSTRANDO MATRIZ ORIGINAL");
        mostrarMatriz(matriz);
        
        int[] matrizorden= ordenaMatrizMenorMayor(matriz);

        System.out.println("\nOrdenada...");
        mostrarMatriz(matrizorden);
        System.out.println(" Termino...");

    }
    
    private static int[] ordenaMatrizMenorMayor(int[] matriz){
        int tamano= matriz.length;
        
        for (int i=0 ; i <tamano; i++){              
            for (int j=0 ; j < tamano-i ;j++ ){   
                if ( (j +1) < tamano && matriz[j]> matriz[j+1]){    
                    int aux;
                    aux=matriz[j];
                    matriz[j]= matriz[j+1];
                    matriz[j+1]=aux;
                } 
            }
        }
        return matriz;
    }
    
    private static void mostrarMatriz(int[] matriz){
                
        for (int i=0 ; i <matriz.length; i++){
                System.out.print(   matriz[i]+ (i+1< matriz.length ?  "," : ""));
        }
    }

    private static int [] cargarMatriz(int longitud){
        int [] matriz =new int[longitud];
        
        for (int i=0 ; i<longitud; i++){                
                matriz[i]= (int)(Math.random()*longitud+1); //aleatorio entre 1 y valor de longitud
        }
        return matriz;        
    }
```

Por convención los nombres de las variables comienzan con minúsculas, por ello cambié tu variable `F` por `longitud`

Comment: Te agradezco el tiempo tomado y por los consejos, me ha funcionado perfecto, lo unico es que me repite los numeros a veces, pero ya le encontre una solucion

Comment: Disculpa, no leí la parte donde dices no repetidos